# PowerShell add-type unable to load assembly

Tags: .net, powershell, add-type

First time asking question so please bear with me

I've come across what seems to be a bug in PowerShell 3 Add-Type cmdlet.

I have a script which makes use of add-type a few times, this script is setup to run via task scheduler every 2 minutes and there are 5 instances of this task and all are running under different user contexts.

The script was written when PowerShell 2 was around and this setup worked perfectly, we've no upgraded our machines to PowerShell 3 and have started getting numerous errors such as below.

```
Error Cannot bind parameter 'Path' to the target. Exception setting "Path": "Cannot find path 'C:\libs\htmlagility\HtmlAgilityPack.dll' because it does not exist."
Generated by: Add-Type -Path $dllPath 
At C:\temp\hpsm-wintel-mbx.ps1:509 char:18 + Add-Type -Path $dllPath + ~~~~~~~~
Stack trace at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.ExpandMshGlobPath(String path, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, PSDriveInfo drive, ContainerCmdletProvider provider, CmdletProviderContext context) at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.ResolveDriveQualifiedPath(String path, CmdletProviderContext context, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, CmdletProvider& providerInstance) at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedMonadPathsFromMonadPath(String path, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, CmdletProviderContext context, CmdletProvider& providerInstance) at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedProviderPathsFromMonadPath(String path, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, CmdletProviderContext context, ProviderInfo& provider, CmdletProvider& providerInstance) at System.Management.Automation.LocationGlobber.GetGlobbedProviderPathsFromMonadPath(String path, Boolean allowNonexistingPaths, ProviderInfo& provider, CmdletProvider& providerInstance) at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand.set_Path(String[] value) at System.Management.Automation.ReflectionParameterBinder.BindParameter(String name, Object value)
```

I can confirm this works when I disable 4 instances and let one run on it's own, and it keeps running with no issues however, as soon as another instance is started the same errors are thrown.

From the various testing I've done, the conclusion that I've come to is that there's a bug in the way add-type works when it's invoked at almost the same time, I find this extremely odd especially as each script is running in a different user context.

To get around this, I've setup task scheduler to randomise execution and no longer get any errors.

Has anyone else come across this or know what I'm doing wrong?